# Uniform convergence of function

Tags: real-analysis, summation, uniform-convergence

Consider $$f_C(x)=\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{\cos(2\pi nx)}{n\log n}$$ Show that it does not converges uniformly and $f_C(x)\geq c\log \log \frac{1}{|x|}$ as $x\rightarrow 0$.

I used summation parts formula: let $a_n=\frac{1}{n\log n}$ and $b_n=\cos(2\pi n x)$, I got the series to be non uniformly convergent: as $x\rightarrow 0$ \begin{align*} |S_M-S_N|&=\left |a_Mb_M-a_Nb_N+\sum_{n=N}^{M-1}B_n(a_{n+1}-a_n)\right|\\
&=\left|\frac{1}{M\log M}-\frac{1}{N\log N}+\sum_{n=N}^{M-1}\frac{1}{(n+1)\log(n+1)}-\frac{1}{n\log n}\right|\\
&=2|\frac{1}{M\log M}-\frac{1}{N\log N}|\\
&=2(\frac{1}{N\log N}-\frac{1}{M\log M})\\
\end{align*}
So the series is uniformly divergent but how could you show the inequality? Thanks

Comment: To show the inequality, you need a lower bound on $\cos(2\pi n x)$ for small values of $x$.  This can be done by looking at the graph of $y = \cos(2\pi n x) $ and comparing it to the line segment from $(0,1)$ to $(\frac{nx}{4}, 0)$.  Once this is done just compare the remaining sum to the appropriate integral.

Comment: How does $(nx/4,0)$ work according to your inequality, $x$ is also the variable. You meant something else?